# Disable the enter key Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I want to disable the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in Chrome extension using JavaScript for a particular page. For example: On a login page, instead of pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> to login the user should click on the Log in button.

I am using message passing in my Chrome extension.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var keys = e.which; 
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getHTML", data: keys});
});
```

Comment: Does the form have enter key listener already? If yes can you show the code?

Comment: the above is the code from my content_script.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) on your handler to consume the event and stop it's propagation.

To make this work on certain pages (not in every one), you can create 2 content scripts: one with the enter prevention function and another with the rest of the functionality.

Then you would include them on the manifest like this:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["common_content_script"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["http://page_i_want_to_prevent_enter"],
      "js" : ["enter_prevention_script"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: but wont that prevent the Enter key on all the pages ?

Comment: just the ones where your content script runs, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Since this extension runs in the background, the content script too, I guess, will run for all the pages. I just want to prevent the Enter key on a particular page.

Comment: Edited the question to include the script only in the pages you want